# Tracing cause of 'The application unexpectedly exited' on shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

One of my shiny apps periodically displays 'Disconnected from the server.'

The chrome devtools log shows the following and there's nothing in the logs in /var/log/shiny-server

Where else can I look to trace what's going on?

Regards
Dave

```
Wed Dec 14 2016 00:30:59 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Summer Time) [DBG]: 5 message(s) discarded from buffer
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 The application unexpectedly exited.

Diagnostic information is private. Please ask your system admin for permission if you need to check the R logs.
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Dec 14 2016 08:41:38 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Summer Time) [INF]: Connection closed. Info: {"type":"close","code":4503,"reason":"The application unexpectedly exited","wasClean":true}
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Dec 14 2016 08:41:38 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Summer Time) [DBG]: SockJS connection closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Dec 14 2016 08:41:38 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Summer Time) [DBG]: Channel 0 is closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Dec 14 2016 08:41:39 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Summer Time) [DBG]: Removed channel 0, 0 left
```

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: No, although it might be "by design" as I think the logs in /var/log/shiny-server only get written if the R process on the server exits abnormally

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same problem and just fixed it!

My code crashed due to these two libraries: XLConnect and xlsx.
When these two buggers were gone and so was the related excel download function, my shinyapp worked wonderfully.

Hope this helps.

Jun

Comment: This is better suited as a comment, please do not use the answer field for this.